# bind dropdown data from sharepoint list and display based on certain value

Tags: dropdown, databind

I have a SharePoint list with field Country and employee. it has 10 records. values of the country are US (for 5 records) and the UK (for 5 records). I am binding employee value into dropdown and used below code.

```
BindDropDown("Employee", "Employee", ddlEmployee, objDataTable);
```

it is showing me all 10 records, but I want to bind only for the US ( means only 5 employees name should be bind and displayed in a drop-down.)
what change I need to do in my code. please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Here apply filter condition in objDataTable to get records for the country US only

Comment: can you share line of code which i need to add or code which i need to modify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(objDataTable);
 dv.RowFilter = "country = 'US'"; //replace Country=column name and US = your value
```

Then pass your dv to your BindDropDown.

Comment: i have used below DataView dv = new DataView(objDataTable);
 dv.RowFilter = "country = 'US'";


BindDropDown("Employee", "Employee", ddlEmployee, dv);

but getting error in binddropdown